# How to draw a line joining mean values on seaborn catplot of box kind?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, catplot

I've some [dataset](https://indianinstituteofscience-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ravisaxena_iisc_ac_in/EQMKEpTYthxDiMRvH2gAWNYBw0kWtcL7o4XMktvmSGZidQ?e=RRcz5n)for which I'm using seaborn catplot of kind=box.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vertdf_dir = pd.read_csv(folder + "/" + filename)
meandf_dir = pd.DataFrame(columns=["NumFlights", "fix", "delay"])


k = 0
for i in vertdf_dir["num Flights"].unique():
    for j in vertdf_dir.fix.unique():
        meandf_dir.loc[k,"NumFlights"] = i
        meandf_dir.loc[k,"fix"] = j
        meandf_dir.loc[k,"delay"] = vertdf_dir[(vertdf_dir["num Flights"]==i) & (vertdf_dir.fix==j)].mean().Delay
        k += 1

sns.catplot(data=vertdf_dir, x="fix", y="Delay", hue="num Flights", kind="box", showmeans=True)
```

[dataplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIibf.png)

In the plot I would like to show a trend where for each "num Flights", as fix increases delay goes down.

Is there a way I can draw a line connecting the mean values(green triangles) for each "num flights"?

The questions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936882/connecting-means-in-seaborn-box-plot), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67975303/how-to-connect-boxplots-with-a-mean-line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71331844/a-boxplot-with-lines-connecting-data-points-in-python) talk about adding lineplots for the boxplots. The category function creates problem like shown in these [undesirable plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bsy8.png).

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible example with correct formatting

Comment: @mozway Hello, I've explained that the question I've asked differs from the suggested answers as they are on boxplot, and mine is a category plot using kind=box.